Distribution of smallest discriminant of number fields of degree $n$
For each positive integer $n$, define $F(n)$ to be the smallest possible absolute value of the discriminant of a number field $K/\mathbb{Q}$ of degree $n$. For example, $F(1) = 1$ and $F(2) = 3$.
By the Hermite-Minkowski theorem, one has
$$\displaystyle F(n) \geq \frac{n^n}{n!} \left(\frac{\pi}{4} \right)^{\frac{n}{2}}.$$
In particular, one has $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} F(n) = \infty$.
Have there been any other attempts to study $F(n)$? For example, is there a conjectured asymptotic formula for $F(n)$?

The two biggest results I know on $F(n)$, an improved lower bound for large $n$ and an upper bound for some values of $n$, are contained at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant_of_an_algebraic_number_field#Root_discriminant I don't know if an exponential upper bound is known for all $n$ - I think probably not.

"Minimal absolute value of discriminants of number fields of degree $n$" is tabulated at https://oeis.org/A006557 but only for $1\le n\le8$. It goes, $1, 3, 23, 117, 1609, 9747, 184607, 1257728$. A reference is given to a paper by Odlyzko, from 1990.

Find anything interesting at that link, Stanley?

@GerryMyerson looking at the smallest list of $n$ for which the smallest discriminant is computed, it seems an interesting question to ask for the Galois groups of those smallest fields, and to formulate a conjecture as to which Galois structures are likely to be small

Was there any discussion of that in the Odlyzko paper?
